# Having a rank deficient matrix warning in MATLAB: Rank deficient, rank = 0, tol = NaN

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure

I've been trying to get this expression plotted in matlab but I keep getting the Warning: *Rank deficient, rank = 0,  tol = NaN* error message.

[image: Mathematical model I'm working on]

```
t = 1:1:14;
n1 = 3.43-2.30i;
lamda = 1550*1e-9;

R = abs((1i*((1/n1)-n1)*sin(2*pi*n1*t/lamda))/(2*cos(2*pi*n1*t) + 1i*(1/n1) +n1)*sin(2*pi*n1*t/lamda)))^2;

figure
plot(t,R)
xlabel('Number of graphene layers')
ylabel('Reflectivity')
```

I'm trying to get something similar to this plot. Please can anyone help me on how to get this fixed? Sorry I'm still a newbie to MATLAB.

Thank you

[image: Plot I'm trying to achieve]

Comment: it seems to be rather the formula than anything MATLAB related. Do you happen ot have a picture of that?

Comment: Thanks @Finn I was wondering too. The reason I attached the formula and the graph. Unless you're referring to something different.

Comment: The result of `sin((2*pi/lamda)*N1*t)` and `cos((2*pi/lamda)*N1*t)` is a vector of `Inf +/- Infi`, so you probably have a problem in the parameters.

Comment: As EBH mentions, the sin() terms grow too large to compute. This can be avoided by rearranging the formula. You are also using the wrong operators (`/` instead of `./`). However, fixing these two issues still does not provide the correct answer, indicating that there is something wrong with the formula itself or the values you input (e.g. `lambda` or `n1`)

Answer (score 0):

The exact error you are getting is due to two things

1. The incorrect use of matrix operations instead of element-wise 'array' operations
2. The fact that `sin(ix)` grows exponentially, so the arguments you are passing to `sin` will return `Inf` (as will `cos()`).

#### Element-wise operations

The `x / y` operator when applied to vectors is interpreted by MATLAB as an attempt to solve for `A` in the system  `A * x = y`.

Replace `/` with `./` to get element-wise division of vectors, which you will need in your expression for `R`.

Similarly, use `.^` to get the element-wise exponent operator.

There is documentation on the difference between 'array' and 'matrix' operators available:

https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html

#### Exponential growth of sin(ix)

To calculate your formula, some rearrangement is necessary to avoid calculating very large terms that ultimately cancel each other. Multiply the top and bottom of the fraction by `sin(2*pi*n1*t/lambda)`, and you find that:

```
th = 2*pi*n1*t/lambda;
R = abs((n1 - 1/n1) ./ (2*cot(th) + 1i*(n1 + 1/n1))).^2;
```

does the trick given your inputs. However, the numbers do not match the plot you provide.

```
R =

 Columns 1 through 13:

   0.44933   0.44933   0.44933   0.44933   0.44933   0.44933   0.44933   0.44933   0.44933   0.44933   0.44933   0.44933   0.44933

 Column 14:

   0.44933
```

I would suggest that you

- Check the units for the formula, make sure that your inputs are in the correct units and
- Check the formula you have given for `R_1`

Comment: This still does not solve the problem, as far as I checked when you use complex numbers for `n1` you get a vector of `nan` in `R` (see my [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288223/having-a-rank-deficient-matrix-warning-in-matlab-rank-deficient-rank-0-tol#comment67845355_40288223)) .

Comment: Added this to my answer - I doubt the formula can be re-arranged to help solve the issue either, so it looks like an alternate approach to calculating the reflectivity would be required. (I'll have another look at the formula later today)

Comment: Thank you all guys, I got that sorted. The issue was with the parameters. The parameters were not right, especially the complex part of the it.

Comment: @TechySupport I thought that might be the case - happy days!